# create dictionary entry containing List<int>

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, ienumerable

So I'm trying to create a dictionary of colours in the form

```
Dictionary<string,List<int>>
```

like so:

```
(colour:colourvals)
```

for example, if the colour was red:

```
("red":(255,0,0))
```

I'm very new to c# (about 1 week) but I have a fair amount of python experience. What I'm trying to achieve in python would look like so:

```
col_dict = {"red":(255,0,0),
            "blue":(255,0,0),
            "green":(255,0,0)}
```

Over to c#, after a lot of tinkering I finally managed to make something that works. This is the current code I have (which seems messy):

```
colDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
colDict.Add("red", new List<int> { 200, 40, 40 }.ToList());
colDict.Add("green", new List<int> { 40, 200, 40 }.ToList());
colDict.Add("blue", new List<int> { 40, 40, 200 }.ToList());
```

**Firstly**, is there a better way to do this?

**Secondly**, I then want to use the list values as the parameters for Color.FromArgb(). Is there some way I put the List from colDict into the parameters like:

```
Color.FromArgb(colDict["green"]);
```

or do I have to store the colour choice and then put each value in like so?

```
this.col = colDict[colour];
Color.FromArgb(this.col[0],this.col[1],this.col[2]));
```

Thank you very much to anyone who can assist me! :)

Comment: There is no need for the `.ToList()` calls in your C# code. You're already creating a `new List<int>`! But if you're going to be always storing three integers (RGB values) why use the overhead of a list? I would consider using a built-in type, or creating a simple `struct`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I see your point, how would I go about structuring a colour? Something like

    colDict.Add("red", Color (255,0,0));
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I figured it out, but I wouldnt have been able to do it without everyone's help!
First create the dictionary with string keys, and color values:

```
colDict = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
```

Then colours can be added like so:

```
colDict.Add("red", Color.FromArgb(200, 40, 40)); 
colDict.Add("green", Color.FromArgb(40, 200, 40)); 
colDict.Add("blue", Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 200));
```

And then the colours can be referenced, and be easily accessed as the "color" datatype like this:

```
colDict["red"];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a `Dictionary<string, Vector3D>`. It is easy to create a Vector3D class/struct yourself as I don't think it ships with the .NET framework:

```
public class Vector3D
{
  public int R{get;set;}
  public int G{get;set;}
  public int B{get;set;}

}
dict["red"] = new Vector3D{R=255,G=0,B=0} ;
```

Comment: TGH got it, thank you very much for the quick answer though, I'm sure yours probably works too, if I had 15 rep yet I would upvote.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use, you may find it easier to store the RGB colour in a single int value.

```
public int ColorToInt(byte r, byte g, byte b)
{
   return (b << 16) | (g << 8) | r;
}
```

You can use [Color.FromArgb(Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833.aspx) to get a colour  from it. Therefore, your dictionary only has to store `<Color, int>` (or you can replace `Color` with a string as the key)

To save you time from having to call the `ColorToInt` method each time, you can create an extenstion method.

```
public static void AddRGB(this Dictionary<Color, int> dict, Color col)
{
   int rgbint = (col.B << 16) | (col.G << 8) | col.R;
   dict.Add(col, rgbint);
}
```

and so whenever you want to add an item to the dictionary, you can do this

```
Dictionary<Color, int> colDict = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
colDict.AddRGB(Color.Green);
```

It will automatically calculate the int value of `Color.Green` and add it as the value for you.

Comment: You're welcome :) Here's a quick explanation of [extension methods](http://www.dotnetperls.com/extension) in case you're not familiar with them.

Comment: from your answer I actually figured out an even more simplified way:
make the dictionary
`colDict = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
 colDict.Add("red", Color.FromArgb(200, 40, 40));
 colDict.Add("green", Color.FromArgb(40, 200, 40));
 colDict.Add("blue", Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 200));`
now I can get the colour like so:
`colDict["red"]`

I'll be sure to learn about extension methods. Your way of automatically getting the colour RGB values is genius, should have mentioned that I wanted to be able to always specify the RGB values! Thank you for all your help! Very grateful.

Comment: I hit enter to try to make a new line, as you can probably tell, this is my first time on stackoverflow hahhahaha

Comment: No problem, happy to help :) Feel free to post it as an answer and accept it in a few days if that's what's solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the ToList as it's already a list:

```
            var colDict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
            colDict.Add("red", new List<int> { 200, 40, 40 });
            colDict.Add("green", new List<int> { 40, 200, 40 });
            colDict.Add("blue", new List<int> { 40, 40, 200 });
```

Access the values like so:

```
colDict["green"][0]
colDict["green"][1]
colDict["green"][2]


Color.FromArgb(colDict["green"][0],colDict["green"][1],colDict["green"][2]));
```

Another alternative for creating the values is using a Tuple

```
var colDict = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<int,int,int>>();
colDict.Add("red", new Tuple<int,int,int>(40,45,49));

 colDict["red"].Item1
 colDict["red"].Item2
 colDict["red"].Item3
```

Comment: Genius, wow, can't believe I didn't try that, seemed to try just about everything else! Thanks for a very quick response!